# Install wxpython on mac

Tags: macos, installation, wxpython

I am new to Mac, have always used windows and I am confused on how to install wxPython. I downloaded the .dmg file from the website, and it contained three files:

a pkg file, a readme, and an uninstall.py

I opened the pkg file, went through the steps, and Im not sure where it installed after it said "Installation Complete"

Also, I did the import wx in idle, which caused a stacktrace error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for development, I would suggest to install (python and) wx using homebrew. It will install version 2.9 and you're ensured that Apple-provided system libraries remain untouched.

Answer (score 3):

From personal experience on installing wxPython on both Windows 7 and Mac OSX, I found restarting the computer helps out after installation and stacktrace errors appearing in the Shell upon 'import wx'. Sounds simple enough, but it worked for me. If no errors appear after 'import wx', that means wxPython installed correctly. To add to bouke's answer above, the current way to install Python 2.7 via homebrew in Terminal:

```
brew install python
```

To install wxPython:

```
brew install wxpython
```